# How make tags with properties in Django?

Tags: django-tagging

The django-tagging app provides basic tagging functionality. I need each tag also to have properties (category, description, etc.), basically a related table. What's your recommendation, should I try to get this with django-tagging or implement "my tagging" from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to hold your tag metadata.

With a tag instance you can look up the model instance to learn the category, description, etc.  You could even tag the metadata instance with the tag if you find that makes things easier.