# How to associate multiple types of tags per model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am little new to django and trying to find best ways to do things instead of writing everything myself. I am working on a model where I need multiple types of tags to be associated with a model and then I want to retrieve the objects using multiple filtering criteria. I see that in django-tagging tags are stored per model so I think its not possible to have multiple tags per model. Ex:

```
   class Place( model ):
     category = TagField() # fun, play, learn, relax
     sport    = TagField() # boating, hunting, fishing
```

Is it possible to do this using django-tagging ? Am I missing something since this looks pretty common usecase to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're talking about so-called *machine tags*. These are tags with namespaces and/or values. (Flickr uses this approach: it allows us to tag photo with, say, `upcoming:event=81334`, and will display this tag as a link to Upcoming event.)

There is an issue for django-tagging, filed back in 2007: see code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/detail?id=14.

No comments by core maintainers, unfortunately. However, there's a ‘machinetags’ branch mantained by Gregor Müllegger here: 
https://code.launchpad.net/~gregor-muellegger/django-tagging/machinetags/.

It's *mostly* in sync with the django-tagging trunk (<del>the latest commit</del> a number of commits is missing though). I remember myself working on some project using that branch about a year ago; it worked fine. Read the documentation on branch and comments on the issue for more details.

Comment: Found a number of related questions (mostly unanswered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251737/categories-of-tags/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477423/machine-tags-referencing-model-instances-in-django, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542388/how-make-tags-with-properties-in-django, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077502/organizing-django-tagging-tags-or-assigning-properties-to-tags

Comment: Thanks Anton! sounds promising, will have a look at it soon

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced in django-tagging, but looking at its models:

http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/tagging/models.py#456

it's obvious that you can only attach tags to models but there are no multiple tag groups per model.
Writing this, you might be successfull in tagging tags themselves, although this is not the best design one could imagine :)

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! I am thinking of writing my own tagging classes/models. It would have been great to use existing Tagging in django.

Comment: You could try modifying Django-tagging that way.

Comment: Yeah that way I will be able to reuse existing code. I kind of expected django-tagging to have this feature.